# GitLab CI with Maven integration tests - Java

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Maven project which contains only Java test classes (No main classes). I use mvn verify command to run integration-tests within the project. Now I want to add this project into GitLab CI. I want to know how I can use my project with GitLab CI to do integration tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer. It was pretty simple.

1. Add .gitlab-ci.yml file to the project
2. Can create Pipeline Schedules in GitLab to run the pipeline as desired.

.gitlab-ci.yml file should contain below (minimum)

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "mvn clean verify"
```